# Saving changes in Beyond Compare does not trigger FileSystemWatcher Changed event

Tags: .net, filesystemwatcher, beyondcompare

This does not make any sense but, as stated in title, when a file is modified with Beyond Compare in a folder monitored by FileSystemWatcher the Changed event is not triggered.

When the same file is modified with Notepad++ the Changed event is triggered.
I did verify that the file is actually changed when saving in Beyond Compare as I opened it in Notepad after saving with Beyond Compare and the changes were there.

Anyone encountered such weirdness before and any ideas why this is happening and how to get the Changed event to trigger when saving from Beyond Compare?

Standard FSW code which is IMO irrelevant:

```
fswDir = new FileSystemWatcher
{
    Path = dirPath,
    NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite,
    Filter = "*.*",
    EnableRaisingEvents = true
};

private void OnFswDirf_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{           
    var filePath = e.FullPath;
    // Not executed when file saved by BC, executed when file saved by Notepad++.
}
```

Comment: Put your code to allow us to get some mistake there...

Comment: A well-behaved program does not modify files.  Far too risky, a crash can cause permanent data loss.  Nor could any program reliably modify a text file.  It recreates a file, you ought to see the create, rename and delete events.

Comment: @HansPassant My code is not in any way modifying the file on disk. The file is modified by Notepad++ or Beyond Compare and when the file is saved in Notepad++ the Changed event is fired and the Change Type is WatcherChangeTypes.Changed, not Created so apparently either Notepad++ is not well behaved or FileSystemWatcher is wrong about the change type. Either way, the Changed event is fired but when the file is changed by Beyond Compare the event doesn't fire so what ever exactly these programs are doing it is not relevant to my problem with the FielSystemWatcher Changed event not firing.

Comment: Not yet sure what Beyond Compare is exactly doing but after I changed FSW Filter property to monitor all files I caught it writing two XXXX.temp files followed by writing one MyFileName~XXXX.temp after which the original file was modified but none of the Changed events fired had the original file FullPath...

Comment: When Beyond Compare saves a file it first writes the contents to a temporary file and then uses the Win32 ReplaceFile function to replace the original file's contents with the new contents.  Based on the error codes, I believe Windows handles it behind the scenes as renames with some additional book keeping.  I would have hoped that would show up in the file system watcher as a change, but it's not the first time I've heard of that technique making other software confused.

Comment: @ZoëPeterson Thanks, that set me on the right track, I think it's the Renamed event that I need to catch...

Answer (score 2):

After subscribing to all FSW events and all NotifyFilter enums I managed to get the full sequence of FSW events triggered by Beyond Compare 4 File>Save function in case someone needs this in future:

1. Created: XXXXXX.tmp file.
2. Changed: XXXXXX.tmp file.
3. Changed: XXXXXX.tmp file.
4. Created: OriginalFileName.ext~XXXXXXXXX.TMP file.
5. Changed: OriginalFileName.ext~XXXXXXXXX.TMP file.
6. Renamed: OriginalFileName.ext file.
7. Changed: OriginalFileName.ext~XXXXXXXXX.TMP file.
8. Changed: OriginalFileName.ext file.

After the process of elimination it turned out that in order to get changes made by BC NotifyFilter needs to be set to:

```
NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Attributes;
```

After that Changed event will capture the file change by BC.